# itself vs very [difference]

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Below are two variants of a conversation about e.g. some rule:

Initial statement:

> His understanding of the rule is wrong.

Reply 1:

> Not just his understanding, but the **rule itself** is wrong.

Reply 2:

> Not just his understanding, but the **very rule** is wrong.

Are both phrases **rule itself** and **very rule** idiomatic? Do they mean the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule itself= modern usage

Less modern: the very rule= rather old-fashioned, might be used in some circumstances in writing. Not usually used in conversational speech.

Both are idiomatic. Yes, they basically mean the same thing.